# Flutter change fab icon on press

Tags: flutter

So I am working on my first Flutter app (android only at this stage) but I need to understand how I go about changing a icon on a floatingActionButton.

Now I understand that I need to somehow make label a variable and then update that variable to change the icon - but I don't know how.

```
 floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
          onPressed: () => { Label: Text('Pause') // This does not work  )},
          label: Text('Play'),
          icon: Icon(Icons.play_circle_outline),
          backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
        ),
```

also tried this

```
 floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
          onPressed: () => {c = true},
          if(!c){
            label: Text('Play'),
          }else
          {
            label: Text('Pause'),
          }
          icon: Icon(Icons.play_circle_outline),
          backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
        ),
```

Full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:audio_stream_player/audio_stream_player.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool check = true;
  String url = "http://18193.live.streamtheworld.com/SAM12AAC066_SC";
  AudioStreamPlayer player = AudioStreamPlayer();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    player.play(url);

  }

  Future<void> audioStart() async {
    // await FlutterRadio.audioStart();
    print('Audio Start OK');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: const Text('DRN1'),
        ),
        body: new Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Icon(Icons.play_circle_filled),
                onPressed: () => player.play(url),
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: Icon(Icons.play_circle_filled),
                onPressed: () => player.stop(),
              )
            ],

          ),

        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
          onPressed: (){
            setState(() {
              if(check){
                check = false;
              }else{
                check= true;
              }
            });
          },
          icon: Icon(check? Icons.play_arrow : Icons.pause),
          backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
        ),

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do so you can use simple variable and on click change the value of that and put it into setState. Following code may help you to understand more clearly.

place this code in your StatefulWidget.

```
bool check = true;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Container(
    ),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: (){
        setState(() {
          if(check){
            check = false;
          }else{
            check= true;
          }
        });
      },
      child: Icon(check? Icons.play_arrow : Icons.pause),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: child is not valid and when I changed to icon it worked but threw another error where it could not find check and then on the emulator screen it shows Assertion failed

Comment: check is a bool variable. please check answer again. it was my mistake of code formation.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool check = true;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Container(
    ),
    floatingActionButton: check?play():pause();
}

Widget play(){
  return FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: (){
        setState(() {
          //Also add logic to play
          check=!check;

        });
      },
      child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
    ),
  );
  }

Widget pause(){
  return FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: (){
        setState(() {
          //Also add logic to pause
          check=!check;
        });
      },
      child: Icon(Icons.Icons.pause),
    ),
  );
  }
```